# Stack view with one static and one dynamic child?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview

I'm really struggling to understand how to make this work how I want it to work, even after reading many dozens of articles and answers.

I want to make a vertical stack view with two `UIView` children. Inside the first child, I want to have a label that's static height. Inside the second child, I want to have a label with a dynamic height (i.e. any number of lines long).

Right now, I have it set up like this:

```
- Content view
    - Stack view (top, right, bottom, and left constraints set to superview, distribution set to Fill)
        - UIView (vertical content hugging set to 251)
            - Label (top, right, bottom, and left constraints set to superview)
        - UIView (vertical content hugging set to 249)
            - Label (top, right, bottom, and left constraints set to superview)
```

This is where things get weird. Sometimes, the second child is really tall (taller than its contents) and sometimes it's smaller than its contents (i.e. if the text in the label should appear on 2 or 3 lines, it only shows the first line).

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I just found that if I remove the second `UIView` and simply replace it with the second label, it works. So why is it not working when the label is embedded in a `UIView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be overthinking this. I created what I take to be your view hierarchy:

[image]

I didn't fiddle with any compression or content hugging values. When I change the text of the second label, the whole thing, right on up to the content view (which is gray so we can see it), adjusts correctly:

[image]

Comment: What constraints do you have set on the labels? Do they have a bottom constraint?

Comment: Yes, of course. Everything except the gray content view has constraints on all four sides. But the views around the labels have no constraints; the stack view creates those. Really it’s just like what you described

Comment: I really don't understand. As far as I'm concerned, I'm doing what you're doing, yet sometimes there will be massive padding above and below the label, but only for some cells.

Comment: I don't know what a "cell" is in this story. The word "cell" does not appear anywhere in your question. It sounds to me like you've asked the question in a way that misses the point of your real issue, whatever it is. What I have demonstrated is that the stack view structure itself is _not_ the issue, because that is what you asked about. If there are "cells" maybe you should ask a new question about that. I answered _this_ question.

Comment: I should add: if this is about table view cells, yes, there can be timing issues with autolayout for table view cells. And if for collection view cells, I do not believe that self-sizing collection view cells even exist (despite Apple's claims). But that is not what you asked in _this question_.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Didn't think it being part of a table/collection view cell would change much.

Comment: I don’t know if it does. I considered the problem you posed, and not some other problem. There are no cells in the problem you posed. The content view is the top of your hierarchy, as of mine.